# android view extraction from OnItemClickMethod

Tags: android, listview

I have a list View and In the adaptor of this list View i have a method

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> AdapterView, View View, 
int position, long id)
```

each row of list contain 3 view

xml for row is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:focusable="false">
    </TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/street"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:focusable="false">
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/pic" android:src="@drawable/pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/name" android:focusable="false">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In OnItemClickMethod i want to find click event on these 3 view. how can i do this?

Note: if i am using view.getId() it is returning -1 for first row . so i am unable to use this one.

```
if(view.getId() == R.id.name){
 dotask();
}
```

Update:  I just call onClick method inside getView Method

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(context,position.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         });
```

and my problem get solved.

Thanks **FunkTheMonk and Vikky.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an onClickListener on Views inside the row used in a ListView.

```
abstract class Clicker implements OnClickListener {
        int mPosition;
        public Clicker(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            //inflate
        }

        //do your stuff
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new Clicker(position) {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int row = mPosition;
                //button 1 clicked
            }
        });
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new Clicker(position) {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int row = mPosition;
                //button 2 clicked
            }
        });
    }
```

onItemClick gives only the selected row, and provides no touch co-ordinates so you can't manually determine which child has been clicked

Comment: so how will i know which row is selected when i will implement onClickListener ? I want to know row as well as view. if i implement onClickListener then onItemClick is not getting called.

Comment: Instead of a new class, you could save the row position into the view's tag and read it on click

Answer (score 3):

Here  in onItemClick View view refers to RelativeLayout and not textviews according to your xml file.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> AdapterView, View View, int position, long id) {

         TextView name = View.findViewById ( R.id.name );
          for other views .......
}
```

Comment: I want to find click event on these view and then want to perform respective action

Comment: then you will have to write clicklistener for those views in adapter itself. Itemclick wont help you in this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use view.findViewById on the view you get in onItemClick. It says here ( http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html ) that it's a relatively lengthy operation, and that the recommended way is using the view's tag to store its relevant child-views. It seems logical, but it might be premature optimization in your case - depending on the number of uses for your view.